# Java multiple processes write to same folder performance issue

Tags: redhat, java-io

We have 4 Java instances each have 20 process writing to same and different folder in Linux and have performance issues on same folder. Below is our configuration

```
Java Instance 1 -  20 process writing to  FOLDER 1 having writing performance 200000 per hour 
Java Instance 2 -  20 process writing to  FOLDER 1 having writing performance 200000 per hour
Java Instance 3 -  20 process writing to  FOLDER 2 having writing performance 400000 per hour
Java Instance 4 -  20 process writing to  FOLDER 4 having writing performance 400000 per hour

3rd and 4th instance have double the performance of Instance 1 and Instance 2 

OS - REDHAT LINUX
CPU - 150+
Memory - 200+
```

Please advise same folder writing on Linux file system will have performance degradation as linux treat folder like files.

Below is our Java IO Code for reference .

```
  File outFile = new File(outputFilePathTmp);
  BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
  marshaller.marshal(baseDocument.getBusinessDocument(),bufferedWriter);
  String outputFilePathXml = regroupedXmlPath+File.separator+outputFileName.substring(0, indx)+"- Regrouped.xml";
 outFile.setReadable(true,false);
 outFile.setWritable(true,false);
 outFile.setExecutable(true,false);
 long outFileLength=outFile.length()/1024;
 baseDocument.setFileSize(outFileLength);
 bufferedWriter.close();
```

Comment: What is your IO configuration? How much IOPS/bandwidth is your disk subsystem rated for? Where is the bottleneck? Did you test the performance with command-line tools, such as dd or fio? What are your units of measure?

Comment: @jurez need to get this info from unix admin . By the way I changed  write to separate folder for process 1 and process 2 and now we are getting the same performance of process 3 and process 4.Above testing confirms that technically  write IO is blocking for the other process to finish. Our issue is solved but curious to know the reason . I will post the details after getting from network team